# Delete a component from the NavBar

Tags: angular, typescript, components, navbar

I am trying to remove the Contacts button on the NavBar [NavBar Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljd17.png). I have tried everything I know and am stuck. I am new to Angular/Typescript, so any help would be appreciated. The code listed below is from the contacts.components.ts file. Also, I have looked through the navbar.component.html page and there is no mention of Contacts anywhere within in.

From contacts.components.ts file:

```
import { IProductConfig } from 'app/interfaces/interfaces';
import { BaseComponent } from './../base.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
})
export class ContactsComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  productOptions: IProductConfig;
  queryUrl: String;
  getContactsContentViewFields: JSON;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productOptions = this.product_config

    this.getContactsContentViewFields = JSON.parse(`{           
      "Description" : {"title":"", "type":"string"}
    }`);

  }
}
```

From navbar.component.html

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li *ngFor="let level1Item of sidebarLinks" 
routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
          <a *ngIf="level1Item.Href" [href]="level1Item.Href" [attr.data-
toggle]="level1Item?.children?.length > 0 ? 'collapse': null"
            [attr.aria-expanded]="(level1Item.isExpanded == true) ? 'true' : 
'false'" [attr.target]="level1Item?.OpenInNewTab ? '_blank': '_blank'">
            <!--<i class="material-icons" *ngIf="level1Item.TabIcon" 
routerLinkActive="white-text">{{level1Item?.TabIcon}}</i>
            <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="!level1Item.TabIcon" 
routerLinkActive="white-text" style="visibility:hidden 
!important;">stop</i>-->
            <p>{{level1Item.Level1Title}}
              <b *ngIf="level1Item?.children?.length > 0" class="caret"></b>
            </p>
          </a>
```

Comment: based on what, you want to restrict ?

Comment: It's not clear under what conditions you want to restrict the contact component. Do you want to disable the click on it or what exactly?

Comment: I want to remove the button altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict access to the Contacts page, there are quite a few ways of doing it.

1. If removing or disabling the Contacts button in the navbar is fine,
   then you will just have to tinker with the HTML code of the navbar.
2. If removing or disabling the Contacts button in the navbar is not
   fine then you could try using [angular route gaurds](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-route-guards/).
   You may return false in the canActivate() function of the guard file in order to always restrict access to the user.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the Contacts button is the goal, but I can't find anything relating to it in the NavBar HTML. I will see if I can find it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, but I have found that sometimes setting the *ngIf to check for **equality** instead of **null checks** works better for whatever reason when running into UI updating. Like :

*ngIf="level1Item == "aValueYouAreLookingFor"

If it's just change detection check out [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html) and [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) ngZone has played a big part in updating the UI in larger operations on my current project so it's worth a look.
I've been working with Angular 4+ since it came out and like Angular JS it can take a few hacks to get things done :-) Good luck!!